# Reactjs Authentication: make route available if you have the link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my application the user is able to create files and to publish them. You need to be logged in in order to create/read/update/delete a file but there's a link with which you can simply view the file (no option to edit etc. and you don't need an account to view it).

Up until now, you needed a token for authentication to create/edit/etc the files in your account, however, if you had the link to the "view-version" of the file, you did not need a link in order to retrieve the file data and to view the file (meaning the route for fetching the data in the view-version was not protected).
However, this seems like a big security risk to me, as you can access the file data (albeit not the user data).

What I came up with is the following:
Besides the file-id, which I use to identify the file in question, I could also enter the token into the querystring, so whoever views the file could be authenticated.
I'm very new to this so I don't know much about what is a security risk. Sending the token in the querystring also seems like a security risk to me but I don't know how else to do what I'm trying to achieve and googling did not get me very far.

To sum it up, my questions are:
1. Is sending the token in the querystring secure?
2. If not, how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm is acceptable to send the token as a query parameter. Google APIs use this strategy in most of their applications. The real security risk takes place during the token request process, to protect user credentials, set a short expriration on the token, however, this will require the user to login more frequently or implement additional logic around refresh tokens.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Comment: Check out Auth0, they have lots of good docs on best practices. You can abstract out their product and apply it to alternative authentication libraries.

Comment: I certainly will, thank you very much for the hint!